# Why does my JavaScript / jQuery interaction with a child window raise a "permission denied" error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, xss, same-origin-policy

I have some code that I would swear was working a month ago. However, now the code throws a 
`permission denied to get property Window.jQuery` error. I can see this error in the Firefox error console.

The code in question belongs to a window that was opened via JavaScript. This code attempt to update the contents of a DIV in the opening page. In an attempt to update this DIV, I try to access it using the following script:

```
var confirmDiv = window.opener.jQuery("#confirmDiv");
```

However, this line is what triggers the permission denied error. Can someone explain to me how to use jQuery to update the contents of a DIV in an opening window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) error.  You're being denied because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), and yeah, it probably worked a month ago, before some set of anti-XSS patches.

In order to do this, your JS and the content it's manipulating need to be from the same domain.